# How to get a copy of a file from removable Sd card to internal memory using C# with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to copy a file from the "removable SD  card" (not external) to the internal storage,  I have debugged the code many times and i can't see any errors  or exceptions being thrown.
 Here my code:

```
private async void btnCopyFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        try
        {
            //RemovableSdCardPath() gets the Path of removable storage
            var directories = Directory.GetFiles(RemovableSdCardPath(), "MyFile.sqlite", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (File.Exists(directories[1]))
            {
                var myFile = directories[1];   // Output: "/storage/590B-3A12/database/"MyFile.sqlite"
                var destination = Path.Combine(docs, "MyFile.sqlite");   // Output: "/data/user/0/ESH_APP.ESH_APP/files/"MyFile.sqlite"
                var starttime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                File.Copy(myFile,destination);
                await DisplayAlert("Copied", (DateTime.UtcNow - starttime).TotalSeconds.ToString(), "Ok"); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

```html
 Debug output:
<iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/7OtEvS" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look closely at the output windows will debugging this code. Any clue there ?

Comment: No, I can't see any clues

Comment: is it able to detect the file? Try doing File or Directory Exists

Comment: did you set permissions to write file?

Comment: Yes, the code is working now, thanks

Comment: so, the problem was permissions?

Comment: A few days ago the permissions were a problem, but now the problem was that the files were hidden and I had to find a way to get information from the files, such as verifying the date they were created, I also had to add the option to overwrite the files.
// add true for override
File.Copy (myFile, destination, true);